# What is the condition required for homomorphism ${\phi}_m : C_n \rightarrow C_n$ to be an automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

If ${\phi}_m : C_n \rightarrow C_n$ is defined by ${\phi}_m(x^t) = x^{mt}$, what is a necessary and sufficient condition on m for ${\phi}_m$ to be an automorphism?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(m, n)  = 1$ I think?

Comment: @q.Then is right. What would happen otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ denote the generator of $C_n$ so $|a| = n$. Then we have a canonical way to view $\phi_m$ as:
$$\phi_m(a^t) = x^{mt}$$
Where $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 \leq t \leq n$. First, note that $(m, n) = 1$, then really, the map takes $t$ and sends it to $tm \pmod n$. So we are really considering $m$ as an element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. If we want an automorphism, we require that $m, 2m, 3m, ..., mn \pmod n$ produce all $n$ values, that is precisely that $|m| = n$ in $C_n \approx \mathbb{Z}_n$. What condition is required for $|m| = n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n \approx C_n$?

If $(m, n) \neq 1$, then we have a common divisor $d$ between them. The proof is extremely similar in showing that if we have a group $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ has order $n$ if and only if $(x, n) = 1$.

**Hint:**
Look at the gcd of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ against $n$.